# mailto link is not working in any browser

Tags: html, browser

mailto link is not working in any browser Google Chrome (Version 45.0.2454.93), Mozilla Firefox (Version 41.0), And Internet Explorer 11 and etc. It is opening a new browser window.

**And I am not able to do change chrome handler settings. I see answer in many already posted questions.**

my code for that is:

```
<a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example.com</a>
```

How to fix it.

Comment: try to this way https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mailto+link+in+html+is+not+working

Comment: Do you have any email client installed? like outlook or other?

Comment: yes I installed **outlook 2013** in my machine.