# Mailto links do not work on my mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mailto

After checking this question ([Mailto links do nothing in Chrome but work in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517600/mailto-links-do-nothing-in-chrome-but-work-in-firefox)), I have tried & determined:

- I originally had this setting (Chrome Settings->Content Settings->Manage Handlers... (`chrome://settings/handlers`)) set for email and calendar links to use the associated Google Service I have an account for, assuming they will try to access the service through the Chrome browser.
- I removed my existing handlers.  Clicking the mailto link still does not work, and I am not able to add one manually through Chrome.
- I do not see a relevant setting in Microsoft Outlook for Mac 15.33 to utilize.
- I was not able to readily reset this behavior to investigate further, as going to Gmail does not reveal the handler icon again:

[image: Set mailto in chrome]

- I experience this problem in both Chrome and Firefox.
- I have tried links without a target attribute, and with one specified to "_top", _parent", and "_blank". ([mailto link is blocked as insecure content in Chrome Gmail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534543/mailto-link-is-blocked-as-insecure-content-in-chrome-gmail))

Mac 10.12.3

Other Links:

- [mailto link is not working in any browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644405/mailto-link-is-not-working-in-any-browser) - (Doesn't Help - No Information)

Comment: This question belongs to apple.stackexchange.com, not StackOverflow

Answer (score 21):

Open Mac Mail and Preferences Dialog. Ensure you have Default email reader set to Mail.app (or whatever app you use for mail).

[image]

Comment: I can't get into "Preferences" because I don't have an account setup in Mail (nor do I want to set one up since I use Outlook).

Comment: If Mail is install you should still be able to open it and press Command + "," to open the preferences dialog even without an account setup. I too dont use Mail.app

Comment: Maybe it should have been like that, but as @daknowles wrote, if you haven't set up any accounts in Mail, the Preferences menu item is greyed out and Command + "," does nothing...

Answer (score 7):

Followed these steps and worked very nicely:

- Run the **Mail** application.
- On the Mail menu, click **Preferences**.
- Click the **General** tab.
- For **Default email reader**, select **Microsoft Outlook** (or what you like).

Source:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3027171/outlook-2016-for-mac-cannot-be-set-as-the-default-application-in-mac-o

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to open mailto link with gmail app inside Google Chrome, but when you click on "mailto" link nothing happens, this is the solution worked for me.

Open "Mail" (the macOs app) , go to "Preferences" and be sure that "Default Email Reader" is "Google Chrome".
Then follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGqZy93oWiM) that provide clear instructions on how to enable the Google Chrome side.

It's first time that i saw a Google Chrome setting so hidden and difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Finally a result!!!!!

I'm on a mac and use thunderbird as my default email client. Suddenly I couldn't select email links in any browser to get it to open. Played with thunderbird, played with settings in chrome etc but as it was every browser I assumed it was a thunderbird issue.

The read about multiple mail clients and realised my wife opened 'mail' the other day. I never use it. SO I went into it and looked at settings.... mail ? preferences > general and there it was in plain english.... Default email reader had somehow changed to 'chrome'! A simple tweak back to thunderbird and all has been restored. How it changed I never know. Amazing that a mail client you don't use can effect how a browser and a mail client you do use works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a relevant OS setting for my Mac, a method similar to Windows' in another Q&A.

In "System Preferences", on the 5th/last row, the first item called "Default Apps", under the "Internet" section, I had Email set to Chrome, that as described before was not working for me.  I set it to Microsoft Outlook, and it performed better with links that did not have a `target` attribute set.

I also found a more granular list of protocols under the "URLs" section, and upon finding "mailto", saw that it was already set to Outlook, probably due to my recent "Email" setting.